# Inferred type error when calling Robolectric.buildActivity()

Tags: robolectric, android-testing

I am using robolectric 2.2.

I am trying out following example code from the Robolectric project:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RoboTest {    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get following error:
`Inferred type 'frontend.android.MainActivity' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should extend 'android.app.Activity'`

Why do I get this error when my MainActivity extends from android.app.Activity?
[image: MainActivity diagram]

Comment: Could you paste the full stacktrace for the error above?

Comment: First of all Robolectric 2.3 is already out for a long time. The problem most probably that Robolectric doesn't see your AndroidManifest.xml. Do you see any warnings when robolectric starts about manifest?

Comment: @EugenMartynov the problem was indeed that my AndroidManifest.xml wasn't being found by Robolectric. And I've also updated to version 2.3 Thanks for the help